# Setting UIButton's title cancels animation

Tags: objective-c, animation

I am not familiar with iOS animation, and here is my problem:

On the login screen of our app, there is a login button. When that button is clicked, we need to move it up then change its title. Moving it up is animated like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                                loginButton.frame = newLoginButtonFrame;
                            }
                 completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
                            }];
```

This works as expected.

Then after we try to change the title in the completion callback like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                                loginButton.frame = newLoginButtonFrame;
                            }
                 completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
                                [loginButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            }];
```

something weird happens: the button "jumps" back to the original position as if the animation was cancelled.

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you using auto layout to set up the button? If yes you shouldn't animate it's frame

Comment: Yes, I am using auto layout -- how should I animate in such a scenario? Any why setting the title affects the animation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using auto layout you should animate the constraints not the frame. For example you can set an outlet for the bottom constraint and animate like this:

```
viewBottomConstraint.constant = 32;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
    animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // Called on parent view
    }];
}
```

You can find more information in the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutolayoutPG.pdf)